# how to concatenate UITextField value in URL xcode?

Tags: url, uitextfield, concatenation

i have this url :

http://demii.com/demo/gearlode/links.php?username=zohaib9&email=n@m.com&password=123&action=registration

UITextField = *usernameTextField

UITextField = *emailTextField

UITextField = *passwordTextField

i want to send username by UITextField, so how can i concatenate my uitextField value in this url please please need help

i m very new here in programing

thanks in advance

Comment: You want to get the values from the URL? or generate the URL from the UITextField values?

Comment: no actually i want to add my *username variable between url where i hard code the username "Zohaib" i want to add my uitextfiled name out there isntead of zohaib. i hope u understand actually m new so hard to define exactly, this is what i want thanks @KishoreK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demii.com/demo/gearlode/links.php?username=%@&email=%@&password=%@&action=registration", usernameTextField.text, emailTextField.text, passwordTextField.text];
```